# How Order of Operations Can Seriously Change The Code Speed?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, variables, optimization

I watched [a video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xd4UhJufTx4) about code optimization from Tarodev. At the end of the video, I am shocked because I saw that order of operations can seriously change the code speed. Although I tried it myself, I don't understand how can it be possible? How can Float x Float x Vector **2 times faster than** Float x Vector x Float or Vector x Float x Float?

I installed Tarodev's project from GitHub and tried it myself. The result was the same as with the video.

### EDIT:

Thanks for all these great answers guys. After your answers, I understood the reason and felt dumb :)  Also, I'm adding a [video Repository and example code](https://github.com/Matthew-J-Spencer/Unity-Benchmarks/blob/main/Assets/_Game/_Scripts/Benchmarks/OrderOfOperation.cs) at **Orhtej2's** suggestion

Comment: I Couldn't understand the exact question of this post. Would you please explain more?

Comment: Try doing a few simple examples by hand, working from left to right.

Comment: 5 ops is always less than 8 assuming a 4 component vector

Comment: The question can be improved by posting the relevant code **in the body of the post**. I'd assume it's contents of https://github.com/Matthew-J-Spencer/Unity-Benchmarks/blob/main/Assets/_Game/_Scripts/Benchmarks/OrderOfOperation.cs ?

Comment: Thank you all guys! I also added a video repository and example code in my question at **Orhtej2's** suggestion!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just first of all

```
someVector3 * someFloat
```

and

```
someFloat * someVector3
```

both basically return

```
new Vector3(someVector3.x * someFloat, someVector3.y * someFloat, someVector3.z * someFloat)
```

so basically 3 `float * float` operations + constructor call of `Vector3`

---

And then the order matters because your operations will be resolved in the order like this

- In the first case you do

  ```
  (float * float) * Vector3
  ```

  so in steps:

  ```
  1. (float * float) => single float * operation => result: float
  2. (float * Vector3) => 3 float * operations => result: Vector3
  ```
- in the second you do

  ```
  (float * Vector3) * float
  ```

  so in steps:

  ```
  1. (float * Vector3) => 3 float * operations => result: Vector3
  2. (Vector3 * float) => 3 float * operations => result: Vector3
  ```
- and in the third equivalent you do

  ```
  (Vector2 * float) * float
  ```

  so in steps

  ```
  1. (Vector3 * float) => 3 float * operations => result: Vector3
  2. (Vector3 * float) => 3 float * operations => result: Vector3
  ```

In the first case you have only 4 `*` operations while in the other two cases you have 6.

**Plus** in the second and third case you also are instantiating an additional `Vector3` (the result from the first operation) which also costs performance and memory.

Answer (score 3):

To multiply a `float` by a `Vector3`, three multiplies are required. To multiply a `float` by a `float`, clearly just one multiply is requred.

When you do:

```
result = a * b * c;
```

That means:

```
result = (a * b) * c;
```

or more explicitly:

```
var tmp = a * b;
result = tmp * c;
```

Suppose `a` and `b` are floats and `c` is a vector. Then `a * b` performs one multiply (`float` by `float`) and results in a `float`, then the second operation performs three multiplies (`float` by `Vector3`). That's four multiplies in total.

Now support `a` is a vector and `b` and `c` are floats. Then `a * b` performs three multiplies (`Vector3` by `float`) and results in a `Vector3`, then the second operation again performs three multiplies (`Vector3` by `float`) and results in a `Vector3`. That's six multiplies in total.

Now, it's *possible* that the compiler might be able to figure out that these are equivalent and do the cheaper four multiplies instead. But often it's not easy for it to see that. And often it's *not* quite equivalent. For example, rounding and overflow can depend very much on which way round you do the operations, and the compiler won't mess with them because it could introduce inaccuracies, so it trusts you and simply does exactly what you tell it.

Comment: Thank you for this answer **Weeble**. I'm sorry for can't mark your answer :( but all answer was really good

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty easy,follow my example:

a Vector is an object made of more than 1 value: e.g. `Vector3 v = new Vector3(1,2,3)`

if u multiply a number for a Vector3, you are doing 3 operations.

```
float n = 3.f
Vector3 v = new Vector3(1,2,3)
```

`n*v` result is a `Vector3(1*n,2*n,3*n)`,so 3 calculations for one multiplication.
following your example in the first case you are doing `n*n*v`,so 1 calculation for `n*n + 3` calculation for `n^2 * v`,for a total of 4 calculations.

in the second case you are doing `n * v * n`,that means 3 calculations for `n*v`  + another 3 calculations for `v*n`,for a total of 6 calculations.

Comment: Thank you for this answer **Riccardo Corsi**. I'm sorry for can't mark your answer :( but all answer was really good

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector x Scalar1 x Scalar2  => (Vector x Scalar1) x Scalar2 => 
VectorTemp x Scalar2 = EndResult
```

So to summarize, we had to operate two times a scalar by vector operation. meaning
2 times a Vector length multiplication.

Where in constrast

```
Scalar1 x Scalar2 x Vector = (Scalar1 x Scalar2) x Vector => 
Scalar3 x Vector = EndResult.
```

Here one Vector x Scalar operation is required. Scalar1 by Scalar2 is only multipication

So I guess the key idea here is if operations are commutative, starts with the cheapest ones.

Comment: Thank you for this answer **user2147873**. I'm sorry for can't mark your answer :( but all answer was really good